# Temporarily preventing matplotlib from re-painting the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter

When using matplotlib in a jupyter environment, it is typical to have it in an interactive mode, which means that as soon as a plotting command is given, the figure changes accordingly.

I have a big matplotlib plot with lots of lines, re-painting the thing takes a lot of time.

Is there a way to prevent matplotlib from re-painting while I'm giving the plotting commands?

e.g.

```
%matplotlib Qt5agg
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Interactive work, everything is fine
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])

# Trying different things...
plt.plot([2, 5, 3, 4, 1])

# Now I'm going to plot something big.
# Hold off on drawing this huge plot while I construct it.
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.random.rand(100, 1000))
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('X-axis')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis')
plt.title('A title')

# Ok, now show the big plot
plt.show()
```